# Conditional php code

Tags: php, joomla

I have a joomla component that I want to rewrite the name of the image files that are uploaded.

The code i have modified is this

```
jimport( 'joomla.filter.output' );

//True to force transliterate
$imgtitle = TTools::stringURLSafe($row->ad_manufacturers,true);
if ($imgtitle == "") {
    $imgtitle="image";
}

foreach($this->data['images'] as &$image) { 
    $src  =$dir.$image->image;
    $dest =$dirfinal.$imgtitle."_".$row->ad_modelauto."_".$row->ad_model."_".$contentid."_".$image->index.".jpg";            
    JFile::move($src,$dest);
    $image->image = $imgtitle."_".$row->ad_modelauto."_".$row->ad_model."_".$contentid."_".$image->index.".jpg";

    $src  =$dir.$image->thumbnail;
    $dest =$dirfinal.$imgtitle."_".$row->ad_modelauto."_".$row->ad_model."_".$contentid."_".$image->index."_t.jpg";     
    JFile::move($src,$dest);
    $image->thumbnail = $imgtitle."_".$row->ad_modelauto."_".$row->ad_model."_".$contentid."_".$image->index."_t.jpg";  

    $src  =$dir.$image->medium;
    $dest =$dirfinal.$imgtitle."_".$row->ad_modelauto."_".$row->ad_model."_".$contentid."_".$image->index."_m.jpg";     
    JFile::move($src,$dest);
    $image->medium = $imgtitle."_".$row->ad_modelauto."_".$row->ad_model."_".$contentid."_".$image->index."_m.jpg";

    $current_images[]= $image;
}
```

It works for me but i have a problem.It wont be used both of the "ad_model" and "ad_modelauto" at the same time and will be only one on the filename.
The question is how can i modify the code to have the field used to be in the filename?
In this situation i will have a space in the filename or _.

Something like this

```
Imagetitle_ad_model(value)__m.jpg
```

or

```
Imagetitle_ad_modelauto(value)__m.jpg
```

What can i do to remove the _ when a field is not used?

Comment: It is really, really difficult to grasp what you actually mean :)